# Spork and Guard EADDRINUSE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, guard, spork

I'm building a rails app and using Spork/Guard/Rspec for testing.

I'm on a mac (10.6.8) -- here are the gems I'm using:

```
gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.12.1"   
gem "guard-rspec", "~> 2.3.3"   
gem "guard-spork", "~> 1.4.1"   
gem "spork", "~> 0.9.2"   
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1', :require => false   
gem "growl", "~> 1.0.3"  
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
```

When I edit my routes file it should restart the spork server here's the line in my Guardfile:

```
guard 'spork', :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :foreman => true do
  watch('config/routes.rb')
end
```

But recently I just started getting the following error when I add a new route:

```
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:861:in `initialize'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:861:in `open'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:861:in `open_server'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:759:in `block in open_server'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:757:in `each'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:757:in `open_server'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1342:in `initialize'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1624:in `new'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1624:in `start_service'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:29:in `listen'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:20:in `run'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/runner.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/gems/spork-0.9.2/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/bin/spork:23:in `load'
/Users/cyrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@h/bin/spork:23:in `<main>'
```

Usually when spork boots up I get the following:

```
Loading Spork.prefork block...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
```

How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

I came here suffering the same problem as the OP.

After going down the rabbit hole of the 'error is a bug' post, and examining the line of code where the failure occurred, I rebooted out of frustration. I realized after doing this that the lock on the port likely came from the fact that I had logged out of the previous desktop session, and that the Spork DRb server hangs RubyMine on closing, so maybe that is what leaves the port open.

Sure enough, I could now start the Spork server.

I add this so other people facing this problem can consider if it matches their situation.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `:foreman => true` in the `Guardfile` I was able to get rid of this problem. Right now I'm not making meaningful use of the values in my `.env` file in my tests so that should be fine, but I'm submitting an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this error is a bug: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8812